# prove that $2^{3n}\equiv 1$ (mod 7) for every integer $n>0$

Tags: number-theory

I used the little Fermat Theorem to write
$$2^7\equiv 2 \ \ \ (\mbox{mod} \ 7) \Rightarrow 2^6\cdot2\equiv 2 \ \ \ (\mbox{mod} \ 7)
$$
$$2^{2\cdot3}\equiv 1 \ \ \ (\mbox{mod} \ 7)$$
Raising to $m$-th power, $m>0$, I got
$$2^{2\cdot3m}\equiv 1 \ \ \ (\mbox{mod} \ 7)$$
And now changing $2m$ by $n$. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Yep, strictly speaking you've proven it only for *even* $n$. Hint of a simpler proof: $2^{3n}=8^n\equiv 1^n=1\pmod 7$.

Comment: If $n=1$, can I put $2m=n$?

Comment: So what about to start with the case $n=1$ and then use my argument?

Comment: Why not use induction as the deleted answer?

Comment: Because this exercise is in the chapter about Fermat and Wilson theorems. That's why I was to use the theorem

Comment: You've written "Raising to $m$-th power, $m>0$". Why don't do this to $2^3\equiv 1$ (mod $7$)?

Comment: @freshman I know that your hint it is right, but as I mentioned I would like to use Fermat Theorem to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

Fermat's little theorem states that if $p$ is a prime number, then for **any integer** $a$, the number $a^p-a$ is an integer multiple of $p$. In the notation of modular arithmetic, this is expressed as
$$a^p \equiv a \pmod p.$$

If $a$ is not divisible by $p$, Fermat's little theorem is equivalent to the statement that $a^{p − 1} − 1$ is an integer multiple of $p$, or in symbols:
$$a^{p-1}\equiv 1 \pmod p.$$

Since, for any $n > 0$, $2^n$ is not divisible by $7$ we have $(2^n)^6\equiv 1 \pmod 7$, i.e., 
$$2^{3n}2^2\equiv 1 \pmod 7.\quad (*)$$
You have shown that for any EVEN $k$, $2^k\equiv 1 \pmod 7$, then $(*)$ becomes
$$2^{3n}\equiv 1 \pmod 7.$$

Comment: I have not paid attention for the fact that I proved only for n even

Answer (score 1):

You can also use induction.

Base case: $(n=1)$:
$2^3 = 8 \equiv 1 \mod 7$. OK.

Induction step:
Assume that $2^{3k}\equiv 1 \mod 7$ for some positive integer $k$.
Then $2^{3(k+1)} = 2^{3k}\times 2^3 \equiv 1 $ (by hypothesis) $\times 8 = 8 \equiv 1 \mod 7$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by "changing $\,2m\,$ to $\,n$" $ $  you assume $\,n\,$ is even, so your argument is incomplete since it doesn't handle the case $\,n\,$ is odd. To fix it, using (only) little  $\rm\color{#0a0}{\rm Fermat}$ (as you require) we can do

$\quad\!\bmod 7\!:\,\ \color{#c00}{2\equiv 3^{\large 2}}\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}2^{\large 3n}\!\equiv (\color{#c00}{3^{\large 2}})^{\large 3n}\!\equiv (\color{#0a0}{3^{\large 6}})^{\large n}\!\equiv \color{#0a0}1^{\large n}\!\equiv 1\ $ by the [Congruence Power Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)

**Remark** $\ $ More generally by [Euler's Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion) we have

$$p\nmid a\ \Rightarrow\ a^{\large (p-1)/2} \equiv \begin{cases}\ \ \  1,\ \,\text{if $\,a\ \ $ is $\ \ $ a square $\!\pmod{\! p}$} \\ -1,\ \, \text{if $\,a$ isn't a square $\!\pmod{\! p}$} \end{cases}\qquad$$

If - as above - we know which case holds then we can use the criterion to reduce the Fermat exponent by a factor of $\,2\,$ when applying [modular order reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242), which may (greatly) simplify computations. As mentioned in the link on the criterion, we can *efficiently* algorithmically determine which case holds using [Legendre symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol) and quadratic reciprocity, so this optimization of little Fermat is generally applicable once one knows these methods.

Comment: Downvoter doesn't know the least bit of mathematics.

Comment: Perhaps @freshman but how much of this does OP understands? He/she has elementary problem with NT. Stinking bishop comment was quite enought.

Comment: @Aqua No, SB's comment wasn't "quite enough" since the OP later clarified in comments that they seek a method that uses little Fermat - which SB's comment does not. Nor does it convey the general idea in the above remark - which many beginners overlook. But downvotes rarely make sense so there's no point speculating.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:
$$
2^{3 n}
  = 8^n
  \equiv 1^n \pmod{7}
$$

Comment: OP already rejected this approach in the comments 4 hours ago. Please read them before posting.